# recursive divison of number

Tags: c++, numbers

I have following code to divide one number recursively by another number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int divide(int number,int dividend){
    int answer=0;
    if (number>dividend  || number==dividend ){
        answer+=1;
        return  divide(number-dividend,dividend);
    }
    return answer;     
}

int main(){    
    cout<<divide(20,5)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but unfortunately I get zero as answer. Do you see what is wrong?

Comment: Try tracing your execution paths manually using pen and paper. The code makes absolutely no sense; for instance, `answer` is never used once it’s been incremented.

Comment: please preview your question next time and do some formatting. Also, please do not appreciate prematurely; even if your intention is to be polite, it is considered redundant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is a local variable. When you run this code, the first call to `divide` creates an instance of the `answer` variable, sets it to 0, and then increments it to 1. Then, when you recursively call `divide` again, it creates a *brand new* instance of the `answer` variable, sets that instance to 0, and then increments that instance to 1.

In your final call to `divide`, it creates a *brand new* instance of the `answer` variable, sets that instance to 0, but since now `number<=dividend` it doesn't increment it, and it returns that instance of `answer` which is 0.

Answer (score 2):

In the `if` branch you are incrementing `answer` but returning something unrelated (the result of the recursive call). I am sure, this is not what you want. Go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You are recursively running the following code:

```
if (number>dividend  || number==dividend ){
    answer+=1;
    return  divide(number-dividend,dividend);
}
```

But once the recursive calling ends (which is `number < dividend`), you will ignore the if statement and **return 0**;

Answer (score 1):

You do **`int answer=0;`** in the start of function call, so when the `if` statement is wrong, it returns `0` so you should define it as input parameter (by reference call) or make it global (not recommended) and do not set it to zero, just set it before your recursive function call.